# Creating a new column based on function

Tags: r

I have an Excel sheet containing employment numbers of each industry of each county in the US.

It looks like this:

```
County   Industry  Employees
a        1         49
a        2         1
b        1         4
b        2         19
...
```

I want to calculate the [Herfindahl-Hirschman index](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/h/hhi.asp) (HHI) of employment in each county. I'm using R.
Given some numbers, calculating the HHI is easy:

```
hhi <- function(x) {
  # calculate sum
  total <- sum(x)
  
  # calculate share
  share <- x*100/total
  
  # add
  return(sum(share^2))
  
}
```

So, for example, county 1 has a HHI of 9608 (= 98^2 + 2^2) and county 2 has a HHI of 7127.

But how can I create a new column with the HHI of that county?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(County) %>% mutate(HHI = sum((Employees/sum(Employees) * 100)^2))

# Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
# Groups: County [2]

#   County Industry Employees      HHI
#   <fctr>    <int>     <int>    <dbl>
# 1      a        1        50 9615.532
# 2      a        2         1 9615.532
# 3      b        1         4 7126.654
# 4      b        2        19 7126.654
```

Or equivalently, use `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)[, HHI := sum((Employees/sum(Employees) * 100)^2), County][]
```

With your own customized function `hhi`, since all the functions it calls are vectorized, you can directly use it with `mutate`:

```
df %>% group_by(County) %>% mutate(HHI = hhi(Employees))
```

or:

```
setDT(df)[, HHI := hhi(Employees), County][]
```

Comment: How do I ignore NA values using the first approach?

Comment: You can specify na.rm = T for the sum functions.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `ave` from `base R` (no packages used)

```
df1$HHI <- with(df1, ave(Employees, County, FUN = hhi))
```